# Concept Idea: Nested Iteration can be tricky

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My idea is quite simple, what I am looking for are pointers, criticisms, critiques and so on.

I understand one can iterate through certain data types, which is great and foundational to any programming language. But where you would require a nested loop (maybe for a comparison) or in my case, to create a simpler and neater way to a for loop that next two iterables in it.

We know that Python can expect a certain amount of values, e.g.

```
for key in dictionary_data:
    # do some stuff with it
    pass
```

Python here expects one value to be unpacked into the left variable from the right variable until, well, I guess it catches a StopIteration or something in the background.

We also know that Python for loops can handle more than one unpack value, like so:

```
for key, index in enumerate(dictionary_data):
    # do some more cool stuff
    pass
```

But lets take the example of a JSON string (or object), which is for all intents and purposes a dictionary. What if we have two JSON strings that we want to compare? And before you smart Alec's pipe up, no, `if JSONString1 == JSONString2` is not a suitable option because I need to compare the individual fields within each of the JSON strings to collate the differences between each version of the JSON string. E.g. In version 1 and 2, there are these difference, X was added, whilst Y was removed.

I also understand that dictionaries, JSON strings, etc, all have the built-in functions to directly access the values of the keys (`.items()`), but this doesn't generally work for nested or double-nested json strings and you will need to nest the for loop to `nth` number of nestings in the json string (if there are 5 levels of nesting in the JSON string, 5 or 6 for loops are needed).

To me this seems quite backwards and counter productive, so here is the long and short of it all;

Is there anything that exists already that can detect how many levels of nesting are present in a json string (or python dictionary)? Furthermore, once detected, could it then extract the keys and values to Python object for later comparison?

So far, this is what I am working with, but it was merely a conceptual design of an idea and by no means finished neither properly tested.

```
import json

js = '{"list":{"entry":[{"recordId":2,"deleted":0,"createdBy":"user.name","created":1542038309023,' \
     '"id":"6e526a31-0e42-4fd9-8a0f-416e12354562", "fields":{"inuseby":"otheruser.name","returndate":1542240000000, ' \
     '"sensor":"93b33535-6273-40a9-a7c3-45dd6a87d4b4","startdate":1541980800000,"class":"fields","version":1,' \
     '"SATstatus":"error"},"ownedBy":"user.name"}]}}'


jsl = json.loads(js)

class JSONHookers(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.js = js
        self.jsl = json.loads(js)
        if self.jsl:

            for key, value in jsl.items():
                self.__dict__[key] = value
                for k, v in value.items():
                    self.__dict__[k] = v
                    for entries in v:
                        self.__dict__['entry'] = entries
                        print('Key: {}\nHas value/s of\n{}\n'.format('fields', fields))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jh = JSONHookers()
```

Comment: I think conceptually this is just a recursion problem. Write a function that takes an arbitrary input (`dict`, `str`, `int`, `list`). Depending on the type of the input (if `str` or `int`) return the value, or if `dict` or `list` recurse farther into the object. There isn't an entirely abstract way of doing this because you need to specify how you want to handle for eg a `list`.

Comment: Do you include tuples and lists assuming that there are these data types present in the json string? As that is not the case, it's only dict keys and string values contained within, however there is 100% at least 1 level of recursion for said dictionarys

Comment: `tuple` is a python type and not valid json so it shouldn't be in your set of objects. i was just giving you a random list of python types that often appear in their analogous form in json objects. if you want this to be a general utility you need to include all python types that map to their analogous json objects. in short, know your input data.